# Azure Active Directory SCIM Mapping

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, scim, scim2

I am trying to implement SCIM in AAD and am having a hard time mapping the fields. When a user is added to a group. In this example i want the following to happen:

*(pretty much what scim does)*

1. User is provisioned, the user is created.
2. User deprovisioned, user deleted
3. User is added to group, the group changes
4. User is removed from group, the group changes.

here is the api information

**getUsers**

Method: `get`

URL: `/scim/v2/Users?filter=userName+eq+%22example%40example.com%22`

response:

```
{
    "totalResults": 1,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "itemsPerPage": 1,
    "schemas": [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse" ],
    "Resources": [
        {
            "emails": [ { "value": "example@example.com" } ],
            "appGroups": [ "Unicorn Team" ],
            "schemas": [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User" ],
            "name": { "familyName": "Family", "givenName": "Given" }, // SCIM requires names, but no real names are stored; you'll always get back these placeholder values
            "active": true,
            "id": "example@example.com",
            "userName": "example@example.com",
            "status": "success"
        },
        ... // more users
    ]
}
```

**addUsers**

Method:
`post`

url
`/scim/v2/Users`

body

```
{
  "userName": "example@example.com",
  "appGroups": [ "Unicorn Team", "Rainbow Team" ],
  "active": true
}
```

response:

```
{
    "emails": [
        {
            "value": "example@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "appGroups": [
        "Unicorn Team", 
        "Rainbow Team"

    ],
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
    ],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "Family",
        "givenName": "Given"
    },
    "active": true,
    "id": "example@example.com",
    "userName": "example@example.com",
    "status": "success"
}
```

**User Config:**

```
 "users": [
    {
      "email": "example@example.com",
      "groups": ["Unicorn Team", "Rainbow Team"]
    },
],
"groups": [
    {
      name: "Unicorn Team",
    },
    {
      name: "Rainbow Team",
    },
    {
      name: "X",
    },
    {
      name: "Y",
    },
    {
      name: "Z",
    },
 ]
```

**putUsers**

method: `put`

URL: `/scim/v2/Users/example%40example.com`

body:

```
{
  "userName": "example@example.com",
  "appGroups": [ "Unicorn Team", "X" ],
  "active": true
}
```

**User Config:**

```
 "users": [
    {
      "email": "example@example.com",
      "groups": ["Unicorn Team", "X"]
    },
],
"groups": [
    {
      name: "Unicorn Team",
    },
    {
      name: "Rainbow Team",
    },
    {
      name: "X",
    },
    {
      name: "Y",
    },
    {
      name: "Z",
    },
 ]
```

**patchUsers**

method: `patch`

URL: `/scim/v2/Users/example%40example.com`

body:

```
{
  "active": false
}
```

response:

```
{
    "emails": [
        {
            "value": "example@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "appGroups": [
        "Unicorn Group"
    ],
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User"
    ],
    "name": {
        "familyName": "Family",
        "givenName": "Given"
    },
    "active": false,
    "id": "example@example.com",
    "userName": "example@example.com",
    "status": "success"
}
```

**User Config**

```
 "users": [

],
"groups": [
    {
      name: "Unicorn Team",
    },
    {
      name: "Rainbow Team",
    },
    {
      name: "X",
    },
    {
      name: "Y",
    },
    {
      name: "Z",
    },
 ]
```

Azure Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups

Answer (score 0):

In order to add user to group in SCIM AZURE AD implementation, you have to implement /Groups endpoint, as appears here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#update-group-add-members
HTTP Patch request as appears in the reference.